# Swiftui: How to reset a Bool State?

Tags: swiftui, closures, state

[image]

When I tap edit, it will show a delete button (minus icon). When the delete button tapped it will show the orange delete option (as the gif shows). Now I'm trying to reset the state back to the origin (from orange button back to video name and length ) when the Done button is tapped.
I'm trying few options like closures but nothing much.
Any help would be much appreciated!

My child view Video

```
struct Video: View {
    
    var videoImage : String
    var title : String
    var duaration : Int
    
    @Binding var deleteActivated : Bool
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(videoImage)
                ...
            if deleteActivated {
                Button(action: {
                   
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.orange)
                            .cornerRadius(radius: 10, corners: [.topRight, .bottomRight])
                        Text("Delete")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    ....
```

My parent view VideosDirectory

```
struct VideosDirectory: View {

    @State var videos:[DraftVideos] = [
        DraftVideos(isSelected: true,title: "Superman workout", duration: 5, imageURL: "test"),
        DraftVideos(isSelected: true,title: "Ironman workout", duration: 15, imageURL: "test1"),
        DraftVideos(isSelected: true,title: "Ohman workout and long name", duration: 522, imageURL: "test2")
    ]
    
    init() {
        self._deleteActivated = State(initialValue: Array(repeating: false, count: videos.count))
    }
    @State private var deleteActivated: [Bool] = []
    @State private var show = false
//    @State private var editing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        //        VStack {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(videos.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                        HStack {
                            if self.show {
                                Button(action: {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        self.deleteActivated[i].toggle()
                                    }
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                                        ...
                                }
                            }
                            Video(videoImage: videos[i].imageURL, title: videos[i].title, duaration: videos[i].duration, deleteActivated: $deleteActivated[i])
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                .animation(.spring())
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                        HStack {
                                            Button(action: {
                                                self.show.toggle()
                                            }) {
                                                if self.show {
                                                    Text("Done")
                                                } else {
                                                    Text("Edit")
                                                }
                                            }
                                        })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided code is not testable so just an idea:

```
Button(action: {
    self.deleteActivated = Array(repeating: false, count: videos.count)
    self.show.toggle()
}) {
```

or almost the same but as "post-action" in

```
}
.animation(.spring())
.onChange(of: self.show) { _ in
    // most probably condition is not needed here, but is up to you
    self.deleteActivated = Array(repeating: false, count: videos.count)
}
```

Comment: It works!! btw, ive been using this " init() {
        self._deleteActivated = State(initialValue: Array(repeating: false, count: videos.count))} " for awhile but not really clear about what is going on. Could you please explain or suggest me any source to read about it? Thank you so much @Asperi